# Where to find the "user library" for the Eclipse JPA Facet with for GlassFish 3.1.2?

Tags: eclipse, jpa, glassfish

I have Eclipse (Indigo) and GlassFish 3.1.2

The "New JPA Project" wizard has the error "At least one user library must be selected."  But there's nothing in the list.

Is there already a JPA implementation in the GlassFish directory, and I should create a User Library that points to it?  Or should I use the download option and get the latest version of Eclipse Link from the web?

Just wondering what is the 'right' way to make the error go away.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me:

Click on the 'arrow down with the disk' icon on the right side, and download the latest EclipseLink.

[image]

Select OK on the screen and you are ready!

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a lot of jars for JSF2.0 Project.

You can use two sort of library to implement JSF2.0:

1) Mojarra

2) MyFaces

Read this excelent tutorial :

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fgettingstarted%2Ftutorial%2FJSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html

In this tutorial you will understand why you need a user librabry with JSF specific library.

Good reading.

Comment: Thanks Quentin, but I was asking about JPA, not JSF.

Comment: The problem is the same, JPA need library to work. The tutorial is just for the explication of the User Library. For JPA you need to use JPA Library, maybe this link for you : http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jpt.doc.user/task_create_new_project.htm

Comment: Hi Quentin, maybe I wasn't clear.  I understand how to download user libraries like JSF and JPA implementations from the web using Eclipse.  My main question is `Is there already a JPA implementation in the GlassFish directory, and I should create a User Library that points to it?  Or should I use the download option and get the latest version of Eclipse Link from the web?`

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question. I think the second option is the good solution because I already have the same problem with Eclipse and I remember it was a problem or library in my project no in the glassfish server. Personnaly I use Netbeans, no configuration required and it's work directly.

Comment: Thx, I wanted to avoid that mainly because it's a big download and I end up re-downloading everytime I create a new workspace.  It would be nice to know if there's a JPA implementation there with GlassFish right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Glassfish does contain required JPA implementation files. Adding following files to a user library should solve the problem.

- glassfish_dir/glassfish/modules/javax.persistence.jar
- glassfish_dir/glassfish/modules/org.eclipse.persistence.core.jar
- glassfish_dir/glassfish/modules/org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.jar